# Каждый раз при вводе нового слова количество слов обновлялось в Label(Количество слов высчитывается в коде, но больше значение не обновляется)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
txt = Text(root, width=110, height=500, font='14', yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

text34 = txt.get(1.0, END)
words = list(filter(None, split(r'\s+', text34)))
s = len(words)

frame = Frame(root, height=30)
l1 = Label(frame, text="Word count:")
l2 = Label(frame, text=s)
frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
l1.pack(side=LEFT)
l2.pack()

txt.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
scrollbar.config(command=txt.yview)
scrollbar.bind('<MouseWheel>')
```

Comment: Если вы заинтересованы получить помощь, то будет гораздо лучше, если вы приведёте такой фрагмент кода, который можно скопировать и запустить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
txt = Text(root)
txt.pack()
label_count = Label(root, text='Количество слов: 0')
label_count.pack()

def update_word_count(event):
    text = txt.get(1.0, END)
    word_count = len(text.split())
    label_count.config(text='Количество слов: {}'.format(word_count))

txt.bind('<KeyRelease>', update_word_count)  # Счетчик обновляется при каждом отпускании клавиши

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: Проверю,галочку поставлю